# GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl api returning nothing

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

```
http://sp.domainname.com/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('listname')/Folders
```

returns nothing but

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xml:base="http://sp.domainname.com/_api/">
   <id>6057dcc8-b07a-4e35-9c5d-def61e835014</id>
   <title />
   <updated>2017-10-24T10:57:18Z</updated>
   <author>
      <name />
   </author>
</feed>
```

and getbytitle works fine
I want to get all the metadata of folders and files so that I can download all the attachments to my local.

Comment: Hi vijay, please goto [contact](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/contact) and ask to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the `/` character.

```
http://sp.domainname.com/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/ListName/FolderName')/files
```

For extracting metadata of a particular file you can use

http://sp.domainname.com/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/ListName/FolderName')/files('filename.extension')